# How do indexes and disk seeks play well together?

Tags: database

I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469806/how-do-indexes-work-in-a-database-mysql-or-sql-server) but i'll be more specific.

I see that when selecting a million row table it takes < 1second. What I don't understand is how might it do this with indexes. It seems to take 10ms to do a seek so for it to succeed 1sec it must do <100seeks. If there is an index entry per row then 1M rows is at least 1K blocks to store the indexes (actually its higher if its 8bytes per row (32bit index value + 32 key offset)). Then we would need to actually travel to the rows and collect the data. How do databases keep the seeks low and pull that data as fast as they do?

Comment: If it takes 10ms to do a seek, you can do 100 seeks and take a second, not 10

Comment: @Patashu: Corrected. I had no idea i wrote 10. I missed a zero

Answer (score 0):

One way is something called a 'clustered index', where the rows of the table are physically ordered according to the clustered index's sort. Then when you want to read in a range of values along the indexed field, you find the first one, and you can just read it all in at once with no extra IO.

Also:

1) When reading an index, a large chunk of the index will be read in at once. If descending the B-tree (or moving along the children at the bottom, once you've found your range) moves you to another node already read into memory, you've saved an IO.

2) If the number of records that the SQL server statistically expects to retrieve are so high that the random access requirement of going from the index to the underlying rows will require so many IO operations that it would be faster to do a table scan, then it will do a table scan instead. You can see this e.g. using the query planner in SQL Server or PostgreSQL. But for small ranges the index is usually better, and the query plan will reflect this.